Calculating all Rectangular Grids with $337$ matches. Australian Mathematics Competition Question
This question is from the Australian Mathematics Competition.

As shown in the diagram, I can create a grid of squares $3$ units high and $4$ units wide using $31$ matches.
I would like to make a grid of squares $a$ units high and $b$ units wide, where $a<b$ are positive integers.
Determine the sum of the areas of all such rectangles that can be made,
where each rectangle is using exactly $337$ matches.



Solution 1:
There are $a + 1$ rows of horizontal matches and each row contains $b$ matches. There are $b + 1$ columns of vertical matches and each column contains a matches. So the total number of matches is $(a + 1)b + (b + 1)a = 2ab + a + b$.
We would like to solve the equation $2ab + a + b = 337$, where $a<b$ are positive integers. By multiplying the equation by $2$ and adding $1$ to both sides, we obtain:
$4ab + 2a + 2b + 1 = 675 ⇒ (2a + 1)(2b + 1) = 675$
The only ways to factorise $675$ into two positive integers are
$1 × 675, 3 × 225, 5 × 135, 9 × 75, 15 × 45, 25 × 27$
We must have $2a + 1$ correspond to the smaller factor and $2b + 1$ to the larger factor.
So the solutions we obtain for $(a, b)$ are
$(0, 337), (1, 112), (2, 67), (4, 37), (7, 22), (12, 13)$
We must disregard the first solution, but we can check that the remaining ones are all valid. So the sum of the areas of all such rectangles is:
$1 × 112 + 2 × 67 + 4 × 37 + 7 × 22 + 12 × 13 = 704$
Solution 2:
There are $(a + 1)b$ horizontal and $a(b + 1)$ vertical matches. Then
$(a + 1)b + a(b + 1) = 2ab + a + b = 337 =⇒ b = (337 − a)/(2a + 1)$
In this table, for each $a$ we work out $b$ and the area $ab$, keeping only those where $b$ is a whole number and $b>a$.

Then the total area is
$112 + 134 + 148 + 154 + 156 = 704$
